# How to add exports to fish like in .bashrc?

Tags: command-line, fish

I just wanted to be able to add inside some fish configuration file (don't know which/where) the same function as this:

```
export PERL5LIB=/home/iaco/workspace/perl:/home/iaco/devtools
```

This line was added inside the .bashrc file and it was able to export the variable each time I opened a terminal.

Is there something like that for fish? I know that I can export variables in fish using the "set" command, but I want to modify one file (don't know which one) in order to automatically add those variables each time I open a fish terminal.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can put the user-specific fish configuration, including set directives, in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`. The contents should look more or less like that

```
set -x PERL5LIB /home/iaco/workspace/perl:/home/iaco/devtools
```

More information can be found in [the documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Adam. The main purpose of this change is to be able to include inside the Perl @inc the path of my local libraries. After added the line you suggested, the export was properly made! But, if I run perl -V I won't see the new paths. I know that this is more a Perl question than a fish one, but I just wanted to know if you (or somebody else) have an idea

Comment: I should've mentioned the `-x` flag. I've just updated the answer, and you can read more about that in the section "Exporting variables" in the documentation.

Comment: The main fish site is down, but the documentation from the fishfish fork is at http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/user_doc/html/commands.html#set (I assume it's the same).

Comment: Does fish have access to environmental variables like $PATH?

Comment: @grant yes, `$PATH` etc can be used in fish, including in config.fish.

Answer (score 24):

Use universal variables introduced in fish 2.0.0. `-x` means exported, and `-U` means that it's declared for every fish session. You can also use the long options `--export` and `--universal`.

```
set -xU PERL5LIB /home/iaco/workspace/perl:/home/iaco/devtools
```

Please note that `PATH` variable is a bit of a special case. While `PATH` can be universally changed, this will affect your current PATH variable (which may be a bit of a problem if an extra path will be introduced by an operating system). For `PATH` variable, use `fish_user_paths` variable (which only adds paths) instead. The variable is an array, which means you don't have to put `:` characters.

```
set -U fish_user_paths /home/iaco/workspace/perl/share/bin /home/iaco/bin $fish_user_paths
```