# How to get color man pages under fish shell?

Tags: colors, manpage, fish

There seems to be a way to get man pages to display in color (see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/man_page). It involves setting environment variables associated with less and adding these definitions to `.bashrc`. I tried doing the same in `config.fish` for the fish shell, but got no color output.

How to get color man pages in the fish shell?

Comment: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add exports to fish like in .bashrc?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33845/how-to-add-exports-to-fish-like-in-bashrc)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Fish uses the set command instead of export. That did not make the man pages appear in color. Hence my question above :-)

Comment: you have to "set" those variables (from the arch wiki) for less or (again from the arch wiki) most.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Yes. I had done that. No color in man pages :-(

Comment: Did you `set -x ...`?

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes.

Comment: Post your config files. Personally I fine it easier to use most.

Comment: This answer is closed, but I have the answer. If somebody reopen it, I can post a real answer. Here is  a link to my solution: http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2ka795/colorize_your_man/clk5fum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the configuration by the following commands,

```
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_mb (printf "\033[01;31m")  
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_md (printf "\033[01;31m")  
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_me (printf "\033[0m")  
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_se (printf "\033[0m")  
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_so (printf "\033[01;44;33m")  
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_ue (printf "\033[0m")  
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_us (printf "\033[01;32m")
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want these colors to be added only when viewing man pages, not for everything you view in `less`, you should set these variables in a wrapper function for `man` instead of putting them in your `config.fish`.

The whole process is to create a new file at `~/.config/fish/functions/man.fish`, and inside it define a function `man` that sets the necessary environment variables, then calls the original `man` using `command`, passing in arguments using `$argv`.

This is my version of the wrapper function:

`~/.config/fish/functions/man.fish`

```sh
function man --description "wrap the 'man' manual page opener to use color in formatting"
  # based on this group of settings and explanation for them:
  # http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2016-08-15/colorized-man-pages-understood-and-customized
  # converted to Fish shell syntax thanks to this page:
  # http://askubuntu.com/questions/522599/how-to-get-color-man-pages-under-fish-shell/650192

  # start of bold:
  set -x LESS_TERMCAP_md (set_color --bold red)
  # end of all formatting:
  set -x LESS_TERMCAP_me (set_color normal)

  # start of standout (inverted colors):
  #set -x LESS_TERMCAP_so (set_color --reverse)
  # end of standout (inverted colors):
  #set -x LESS_TERMCAP_se (set_color normal)
  # (no change – I like the default)

  # start of underline:
  #set -x LESS_TERMCAP_us (set_color --underline)
  # end of underline:
  #set -x LESS_TERMCAP_ue (set_color normal)
  # (no change – I like the default)

  command man $argv
end
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! And to get even more fishy you can use the `set_color` command. e.g.: `set -x LESS_TERMCAP_md (set_color -o red)`, `set -x LESS_TERMCAP_me (set_color normal)`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you use less as your pager, put this in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_mb (printf "\e[01;31m")
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_md (printf "\e[01;31m")
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_me (printf "\e[0m")
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_se (printf "\e[0m")
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_so (printf "\e[01;44;33m")
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_ue (printf "\e[0m")
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_us (printf "\e[01;32m")
```

If you see `\e[0m` etc appearing when you view the man page, try adding this line as well:

```
set -x LESS "-R"
```

Comment: Not working. I see the \e[01 strings when I do "man ls".

Comment: Strange, I believe this was straight from my config file. I haven't actually tried it on Ubuntu, though, as I run a different distro myself. Maybe you could try adding `set -x LESS="-R"` to the end of your config?

Comment: Adding that did not help. Still seeing same \e[01 strings in manpage.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use `set_color` instead of direct ANSI sequences. In fact, this allows you to use any color you want, by using 24-bit color hexadecimal escapes, like `(set_color FF55AA)`.

```
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_mb (set_color brred)
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_md (set_color brred)
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_me (set_color normal)
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_se (set_color normal)
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_so (set_color -b blue bryellow)
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_ue (set_color normal)
set -x LESS_TERMCAP_us (set_color brgreen)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a very nice tool called **batcat** provided by https://github.com/sharkdp/bat.

`bat` package is available on Ubuntu since 20.04 ("Focal") and Debian since August 2021 (Debian 11 - "Bullseye")and its command is `batcat` which is a **cat replacement with wings**.

From the git docu:

> ##### `man`
>
> `bat` can be used as a colorizing pager for `man`, by setting the
> `MANPAGER` environment variable:
>
> ```
> bash export MANPAGER="sh -c 'col -bx | batcat -l man -p'"
> ```
>
> It might also be necessary to set `MANROFFOPT="-c"` if you experience
> formatting problems.
>
> If you prefer to have this bundled in a new command, you can also use
> [batman](https://github.com/eth-p/bat-extras/blob/master/doc/batman.md).
>
> Note that the Manpage
> syntax is developed
> in this repository and still needs some work.
>
> Also, note that this will [not
> work](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/issues/1145) with Mandocs `man`
> implementation.

Install this bat package

```
sudo apt install bat
```

I love the Monokai theme and therefore I added this command into my `.zshrc`:

```
export MANPAGER="sh -c 'col -bx | batcat -l man -p --theme 'Monokai Extended''"
```

In case you are using `fish` shell add this line to your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file:

```
set -x MANPAGER "sh -c 'col -bx | batcat -l man -p --theme 'Monokai Extended''"
```

A list of installed color-themes can be printed by following command

```
batcat --list-themes
```

Here a screenshot of `man 3 printf`

[image]

Comment: You may need to add `export MANROFFOPT="-c"` to make this work correctly